# Microsoft Sync Framework Newbie - Argument Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio, microsoft-sync-framework

I am very new to windows mobile development and MSFT Sync Framework as a heads up. I have a simple application that reads a barcode, retrieves entry from a database and lets the user enter a new reading. That all works just fine. However, when I attempt to synchronize I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="ArgumentException"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy.ApplyChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, DataSet dataSet, SyncSession syncSession)
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.UploadChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata)
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.Synchronize()
       at ElectricBarcodeApp.Form1.buttonSync_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
       at ElectricBarcodeApp.Program.Main()
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ElectricBarcodeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(
            ("Data Source=" + (Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047"))))
            {

                // Connect to the local database 
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
                    param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
                    param.DbType = DbType.String;
                    param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();

                    // SELECT rows
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE Barcode LIKE @Barcode";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                    DataTable data = new DataTable();

                    using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                            data.Load(reader);
                            this.dataGrid1.DataSource = data;

                    }

                }
            }


        }

        private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(
            ("Data Source=" + (Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047"))))
            {

                // Connect to the local database 
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {

                    // INSERT NEW READING
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Main2 SET Reading = '" + textNewReading.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE Barcode LIKE '" + textBarcode.Text.Trim() + "'"; 

                    int m = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (m > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("New Reading Successfully Entered:" + textNewReading.Text.Trim(), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        private void buttonSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The WCF Service
            ElectricReadingCacheWebRef.ElectricReadingCacheSyncService webSvcProxy = new
                ElectricBarcodeApp.ElectricReadingCacheWebRef.ElectricReadingCacheSyncService();

            // The Remote Server Provider Proxy
            Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy serverProvider = new
                Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy(webSvcProxy);

            // The Sync Agent
            ElectricReadingCacheSyncAgent syncAgent = new ElectricReadingCacheSyncAgent();
            syncAgent.RemoteProvider = serverProvider;
            //Main2 is the table to be synchronized
            syncAgent.Main2.SyncDirection = Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncDirection.Bidirectional;

            // Synchronize the databases
            Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics stats = syncAgent.Synchronize();

            // Show synchronization statistics
            MessageBox.Show("Changes Downloaded: " + stats.TotalChangesDownloaded.ToString() +
                "\r\n" + "Changes Uploaded: " + stats.TotalChangesUploaded.ToString());

        }



    }
}
```

The exception is thrown at this line:

```
// Synchronize the databases
                Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics stats = syncAgent.Synchronize();
```

I have been getting nowhere on finding a solution and any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I thought it might be because I did not have:

```
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
```

But adding that did not change the exception.

Comment: If you didn't have the `using` statements the code wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: You should also post the ElectricReadingCacheSyncAgent code, since it's the place where excpetion is thrown.

Comment: this seems to be an error related to WCF, how did you generate the client side proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click Your web reference to open it in Object Browser.

Expand the node YourAppName.YourAppNameCacheWebRef.

Right-click YourNameCacheSyncService and click Go To Definition.

`Reference.cs` is opened in the Code Editor.

Add the following code after the last using or imports statement:

```
Imports Microsoft.Synchronization
Imports Microsoft.Synchronization.Data
```

Or, in C#:

```
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
```

Remove all classes and enumerations in the file except for YourNameCacheSyncService.